# DT::datatable download buttons download only the -visible in app- part of the data

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Im trying to download the whole dataset that I display in the datatable of the `shiny` app as excel file but the buttons only download the visible in app part instead of all rows.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)



ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    dataTableOutput("TABLE"),
  )
)

server <- (function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$TABLE_cell_edit, {
    mtcars <<- editData(mtcars, input$TABLE_cell_edit, 'TABLE')
  })
  
  output$TABLE <- renderDataTable({
    input$TABLE_cell_edit
    
    datatable(mtcars,
              filter = "top", editable = "cell", class = "hover cell-border stripe",
              caption = "Owners wit more than 500 aggregated accrs",
              extensions = "Buttons",
              options = list(
                dom = "Bfrtip",
                buttons = c("copy", "csv", "excel")
              )
    )
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok server=F makes it

```
renderDT(server=FALSE,{
  # Load data
  data <- mtcars
  # Show data
  datatable(data, extensions = 'Buttons', 
            options = list(scrollX=TRUE, lengthMenu = c(5,10,15),
                           paging = TRUE, searching = TRUE,
                           fixedColumns = TRUE, autoWidth = TRUE,
                           ordering = TRUE, dom = 'tB',
                           buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel','pdf')))
})
```